# Php: Exposing private members of a class

Tags: php, oop, object

I have a class `User` which has private properties of a user and public interfaces. I am trying to expose those properties through OOP in order to bind their `$key=>value` to some sql parameters, but I can iterate over private members in order to extract the data. I have saw the `var_dump()` method which is usually used for debugging, so I created a public interface `userInfo()` that would return that object as an array. However, that just seems like a hack and not a real eloquent way of exposing or sharing data across this application. Ive read tons of articles and in class we are taught to keep members private and expose them through public interfaces. I know there is the protected member access, but is that eloquent enough? So, how would a "good", and I know that subjective, coder share this data across the application?

EDIT: Cannot use protected because nothing extends the user class

```
class User{

private $firstname
private $lastname
private $username
private $password

public getFirstName(){}
public getLastName(){}
public getUsername(){}
public getPassword(){}

public userInfo(){
return get_object_vars($this)
}

}
```

Comment: although writing getters and setters is a lot of boilerplate to write, they **are** best practice.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann so yes i have getters and setters so i should call all those functions in order to get the data?

Comment: yes............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has [overloading / magic methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members) exactly for this purpose. You don't need to programmatically think of every possible value / field. Have a look at the below example:

```
class MyClass {

    private $firstField;
    private $secondField;

    public function __get($property) {

        if ( property_exists($this, $property) ) {
            return $this->$property;
        }
    }

    public function __set($property, $value) {

        if ( property_exists($this, $property) ) {
            $this->$property = $value;
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```